# PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object

Tags: database, foreach, pyspark

Anyone who knows how to debug this:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: Cannot serialize socket object
```

I tried to test writing my database with foreach in pyspark by running a simple example:

```
dt = sc.parallelize(range(1, 1000))

def writeBatchData(b):

    session = driver.session()

    session.run('UNWIND {batch} AS row CREATE (n:Node {v: row})', {'batch': b})

    session.close()

dt.foreach(writeBatchData)
```